# Duplicates in the result of a subquery

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to count distinct sessionIds from a measurement. `sessionId` being a tag, I count the distinct entries in a "parent" query, since `distinct()` doesn't works on tags.
In the subquery, I use a `group by sessionId limit 1` to still benefit from the index (if there is a more efficient technique, I have ears wide open but I'd still like to understand what's going on).

I have those two variants:

```
>  select count(distinct(sessionId)) from (select * from UserSession group by sessionId limit 1)
name: UserSession
time count
---- -----
0    3757
```

```
>  select count(sessionId) from (select * from UserSession group by sessionId limit 1)
name: UserSession
time count
---- -----
0    4206
```

To my understanding, those should return the same number, since `group by sessionId limit 1` already returns distinct sessionIds (in the form of groups).

And indeed, if I execute:

```
select * from UserSession group by sessionId limit 1
```

I have 3757 results (groups), not 4206.

In fact, as soon as I put this in a subquery and re-select fields in a parent query, some sessionIds have multiple occurrences in the final result. Not always, since there is 17549 rows in total, but some are.

This is the sign that the `limit 1` is somewhat working, but some sessionId still get multiple entries when re-selected. Maybe some kind of undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that I get the same result.
In my experience using nested queries does not always deliver what you expect/want.

Depending on how you use this you could retrieve a list of all values for a tag with:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM UserSession WITH KEY=sessionId
```

Or to get the cardinality (number of distinct values for a tag):

```
SHOW TAG VALUES EXACT CARDINALITY FROM UserSession WITH KEY=sessionId.
```

Which will return a single row with a single column `count`, containing a number. You can remove the `EXACT` modifier if you don't need to be exact about the result: [SHOW TAG VALUES CARDINALITY on Influx Documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/spec/#show-tag-values-cardinality).

Comment: Thanks, I am reassured in a way. that `show tag` feature is great. I achieved what I wanted to do (a simple count) with `show tag values exact cardinality` (I'll edit you answer to reflect that). I'll accept you answer, until someone eventually posts an explication about why subqueries behave like this. The upvote will be for the `show tag` based solution ;)

Comment: oh, nice catch with the cardinality!

Comment: Ah, unfortunately, `SHOW TAG` can't take time filters in `WHERE` clause, and I need this. https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5668
I'll have to get back to my previous solution. InfluxDB is cool when it works, but it's so full of surprising behaviours. Writing a query can be such a pain.